# Laravel Routing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

В роуте:

```
Route::get('{username}/board', 'User\BoardController@index')->where('username', '[A-Za-z0-9]+')->name('user_board');
Route::get('{username}/edit', 'User\EditController@index')->where('username', '[A-Za-z0-9]+')->name('user_edit');
...
```

В каждом контролере я делаю проверку

```
public function index($username){

    if(Auth::user()->login != $username){
            return redirect()->route('user_board', ['username' => Auth::user()->login]);
    }
}
```

Возможно ли сократить эту проверку на уровне каждого роута?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckUsername
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $username = $route = $request->route('username');
        if($user->login !== $username){
            return redirect()->route('user_board', ['username' => $user->login]);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Регестрируем в `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'username' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUsername::class,
    ...
];
```

И наконец используем в нужных маршрутах:

```
Route::get('{username}/board', 'User\BoardController@index')
    ->where('username', '[A-Za-z0-9]+')
    ->name('user_board')
    ->middleware('username');

Route::get('{username}/edit', 'User\EditController@index')
    ->where('username', '[A-Za-z0-9]+')
    ->name('user_edit')
    ->middleware('username');
```

Answer (score 3):

Может проверку

```
->where('username', '[A-Za-z0-9]+')
```

тоже вынести в посредник

Comment: или еще лучше вынести в RouteServiceProvider через [Global Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)

Comment: В RouteServiceProvider
    public function boot()
    {
        Route::patterns(['username'=>'[A-Za-z0-9]+']);
        parent::boot();
    }